# Unable To Publish To AWS Lambda From Visual Studio 2017

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to take an existing .net core API project and run it as a lambda function (Which should be possible).

I have installed the VS 2017 SDK for AWS. While following tutorials, I am supposed to be able to right click my project and select deploy to AWS Lambda. The only option I have is "Publish To Elastic Beanstalk"

[image]

However, when I create a brand new empty function in Visual Studio (New Project). I do have the ability to Publish To Lambda

[image]

But I can't seem to figure out the difference between the projects. Every nuget/tooling reference between the two projects is identical when it comes to AWS Packages.

Answer (score 4):

My answer was the following, in my csproj I had the following line :

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Tools " Version="1.5.0" />
```

Notice there is a small space after Tools. No complains from VS though so it was super hard to spot, and only exists because you have to edit the csproj manually when adding DotNetCliTools.